# ngGrid multiselect is not updating the selected items after data is reloaded

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

NgGrid multiselect is not updating the selected items after the grid data is been modified.How to solve this issue?

Comment: it is updating the selected items.

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/RacXc8?p=preview

Hey, check this plunkr. I think you don't understand something. It works fine, as you can easily see in the plunkr.